# KAlarm won't start at login

Tags: settings, autostart

I installed KAlarm *(A KDE software)* in my Ubuntu 11.10 and checked off "Start at Login", but it doesn't.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you installed it in Ubuntu or Kubuntu? or Do you have KDE desktop installed?

Answer (score 2):

This [documentation about Kalarm](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdepim/kalarm/faq.html) may help you too, apparently Kalarm has another script for starting on login.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Autostart. Click on "Add Program".
Open System Settings using

```
sudo systemsettings
```